# Using .click function to show element, in a table. How do I differentiate between elements inside a table that is populated using a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

How do I differentiate between elements inside a table that is populated using a loop? So that when I use Javascript to show an element on click, it will show the correct element?

Currently, when I click comment, it just shows the first item, and then the rest of the rows don't work.

When the user clicks the comment button, I want a textarea to appear. The problem is that since it is a table, how do i make it so each comment button in the table shows the box within its table. do i need to add an incrementing id to each row in the table?

**Here is the Javascript:**

```
$('#postcomment').click(function(){
$('#comment_text').css('display','inline');
})
```

**Here is the PHP:**

```
<table>
<?php
foreach ($posts as $key => $list){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>
<a id='postcomment'>Comment</a>
<textarea  id='comment_text' style='display:none;placeholder='Type your comment.'></textarea>
      </td>";
echo "</tr>";               
}
?>
</table>
```

Is the best solution for this, to give each row a unique id, and how would I do this? Also, how would I then call the Javascript to work for each unique id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id`s must be unique within a document.  Instead use a class.  Once you do that, you can use things such as `parent`, `siblings`, `find`, etc. to find the appropriate element based on the location of the one you clicked.

Something like this:

```
$('.postcomment').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.comment_text').css('display','inline');
});
```

Comment: i tried it and it is not working for some reason. even though it should work.